# Image won't draw onto screen but no errors occur

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, paint

I've started creating a simple java game and at the moment I have the Game Window created with a screen and a basic Player class. The player image however won't draw onto the screen despite the program not giving me any errors so I'm not sure where to start debugging for the problem maybe someone could help me out?

Here are the classes:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameWindow extends JFrame {

public static int windowWidth = 600;
public static int windowHeight = 600;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameWindow();
}

public GameWindow() {
    this.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    this.setTitle("Berzerk Clone");
    this.setVisible(true);
    // Defaults the window to be set in the middle of the screen
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GameDrawing drawGame = new GameDrawing();
    this.add(drawGame, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

}
```

Drawing Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameDrawing extends JComponent {

PlayerHuman p;

public GameDrawing() {      
    p = new PlayerHuman(300, 300);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;

    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, GameWindow.windowWidth,GameWindow.windowHeight);
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    graphics.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), 300, 300, null);
}
}
```

Player class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;

public class PlayerHuman extends GlobalPosition {

BufferedImage basicPlayer;  

public PlayerHuman(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
    try {
        basicPlayer = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Player.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImage(), x, y, null);
}

public BufferedImage getPlayerImage() {
    return basicPlayer;
}

}
```

All help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

My Apologies

GlobalPosition Class to give the player a starting point:

```
public class GlobalPosition {

public int x;
public int y;

public GlobalPosition() {
    x = y = 0;
}

public GlobalPosition(int _x, int _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(int newX) {
    x = newX;
}

public void setY(int newY) {
    y = newY;
}

}
```

I have a Game Loop class that repaints:

```
public class GameLoop implements Runnable {

GameWindow gWindow;

public GameLoop(GameWindow newGWindow) {
    this.gWindow = newGWindow;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    gWindow.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me... What is `GlobalPosition`?

Comment: Start small: test a very small program that does nothing but loads an image, puts it into an ImageIcon and displays the ImageIcon in a JOptionPane. Solve that first, and only **then** work on using it in the larger application. Also, you're better off reading the image in as a URL via `getClass().getResource("....")` than as a File.

Comment: My guess is that you need to `repaint()`, but I can't compile due to GlobalPosition not being found.

Comment: @mathguy54: He needs to first make sure that he is looking in the right place for the image. Again, start small.

Comment: Also, don't call `setVisible(true)` on the top-level window until **after** adding all components.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Regarding "also don't call setVisible(true)", that's probably why repaint() needs to be called, assuming the image can be located.

Comment: Edit should include the forgotten classes sorry. Taking on board about using "getClass().getResource()" I would have got an error if the image couldn't be found wouldn't I?

Comment: @Schonge, what is the location of your target image ? If the the application jar contains it then yes your will have to use `getClass().getResource()`: getting error is a good thing. It tells what wrong thing you are even trying. So confirm your image location first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Start small: test a very small program that does nothing but loads an image, puts it into an ImageIcon and displays the ImageIcon in a JOptionPane. Solve that first, and only **then** work on using it in the larger application.
- You're better off reading the image in as a URL via `getClass().getResource("....")` than as a File.
- don't call `setVisible(true)` on the top-level window until **after** adding all components.
- Override the JComponent's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, not its paint method.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowImage {

   // ******* add the path to the image resource below *****
   private static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE_PATH = "";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      URL imgUrl = ShowImage.class.getResource(IMAGE_RESOURCE_PATH);
      BufferedImage img;
      try {
         img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
         if (img == null) {

            String message = "Image cannot be found at \""
                  + IMAGE_RESOURCE_PATH + "\"";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
            System.exit(-1);

         }
         Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was the

```
setVisible(true)
```

call that was causing the problem. I pushed it below all the other calls in the method and the screen and image appeared. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

@Sage this is the location so the location is correct, however I will begin to use the

```
getClass().getResource(..)
```

method from now on.

[image]